# Encrypted database, and partial decryption of columns

Tags: cryptography, databases

Assuming that I have an database which stores attributes about individuals (e.g. age, gender, address etc.), and this database is encrypted.

Some users will need to access the database, however not all users will need access to all attributes

User 1 may only need access to "age"

User 2 may require access to "age" and "gender"

Is there a way to achieve this?

edit: assumption is that there is only 1 master key for the database, but when users need to access the database, they may only be granted access to read certain attributes (i.e. columns)

Comment: The reason this question has been put on hold is because the answer is simply, "Yes, there are many ways." Without more information it is difficult to answer. You may have better luck researching some possibilities and specifically asking about the differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Encrypt each column with a different key and only provide a user with the relevant set of keys.
- Implement column-level security in your DBMS
- Write a middleware that implements your restrictions and is the only one to have access to the database.

Comment: The first would be inconvenient if one decided to change the access privileges.

Comment: Yup. But again, it's not as if we were provided with any kind of requirement list, use case, threat model, etc. So I thought I'd mention it :)

Comment: Hi Stephane, thanks for the reply. Sorry forgot to state my assumption that there is only 1 master key that encrypts all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on what type of DBMS we are talking about.

In most relational DBMS it is possible to

- deny the users access to the table,
- create views and
- grant access based on the view.